# Dell Latitude e6420 128GB SDXC Card

Tags: compatibility, dell-latitude, sdxc

I am using a Dell Latitude e6420 at work with a 120GB SSD which is running out of space due to many VirtualBox drives for testing various browsers.

I am looking at a couple of options for expanding storage.

I would like to use a 128GB SDXC card but I cannot find any confirmation that these cards are supported. I found a couple of forum posts speculating that 64GB cards should work.

Is any one using a Latitude e6420 and 128GB SDXC cards?

Comment: All you need to confirm is if you have a SDXC expansion port.  If you do then any SDXC device is supported.

Comment: According to a Dell support forum post the SD card reader supports SDXC. Thanks you!